# C++ Data Structure for Nested Number Lists

Tags: c++, data-structures

I need an efficient C++ implementation of a data structure that can store nested lists of numbers, such as:

```
0: 
   1: 
      3
      4
      7
   5: 
      10
      13
      15
   7: 
      2
1:
   1: 
       2
       3
   6: 
       7
       9
```

I want to be able to loop over the deepest elements in a very efficient manner, so that I can access sets of three numbers in this order that they appear in the nested list:

```
(0,1,3)
(0,1,4)
(0,5,10)
...
```

I also wish to add elements to the tree by passing a set of three numbers and having the appropriate numbers added to each level of the tree. I believe that I should use some type of tree data structure for this, but do not know which one would be most efficient.

Finally, I want to associate a value with each "leaf", so each triple will map to some integer value.

Comment: It looks like a binary tree

Comment: Oh sorry they can have more than 2 children at any level though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Trie is likely to be the most efficient structure for something like this. You can find an overview on what Trie's are [here](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/tree/trie/).

Essentially Trie's store values where there are liable to be many overlaps early in the values (like strings or sequences of numbers), by only storing each value at each position once. The diagram you drew almost exactly depicts a Trie.

Comment: Thank you. Given that I need to iterate over the elements in order, it seems the Trie is most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what you want.

A quick solution would just be a `std::map<std::tuple<int, int, int>, ValueType>`, where in your example the `ValueType` would just be `int`.

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
class Node
{
    //optional - depends on whether you need it:
    std::weak_ptr<Node> parent;

    //for the children, you might want this (if they are numbered 0, 1, ...)
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> children;

    //or instead you might want this for the children
    //(if they are numbered with potential gaps, like in your example):
    std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Node>> children;
};

class LeafNode : Node
{
    ValueType data; //ValueType is whatever you want
}
```

Comment: I suppose a map-based implementation would be the simplest..it would just require storing about triple the data for the numerical keys

Comment: @SamManzer "A quick solution..." - Depending on the OP's application, he might not be at all worried about memory usage. If he is, something more advanced could be used.

Answer (score 0):

It's very like to [suffix trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree). But which one is more convenient for you.. solve you.